# FME 2016 - FeatureMerger, row data to columns

Tags: fme-form, features

I'm not able to get it work to "dissolve" data from rows to columns based on a join field.

My source is connected twice to the FeatureMerger in FME 2016. It's connected to the Requester port and to the Supllier port.
The join is made on column id and Process Duplicates is set to Yes.

Below is an image of the source and I want to achieve (ESTIMATED RESULT). See image.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Dear Jorge. Thank you for your answer.I think it's not the proper transformer. If I look at your sample (and understand it the right way) the values are summarized based on the id (Group by). I just want to replace the values, so the value of the second row for id 1 in col2 (70) should "move up" to the first row for id 1 in col2 (now has value 0). The value of the third row for id 1 in col4 (12) should "move up" to the first row for id 1 in col4. etc etc. I hope you understand.....

Comment: From what I can see, you want the maximum value in each column for every id.  If so, then in fact, Jorge's answer is correct.  However, rather than applying the 'sum' function, you need to specify maximum attribute.

Answer (score 3):

looking into this example i would go for a statistictsCalculator grouping by id , attributes to analyse your columns 
[image: statistics calc]

[image]